# Inno Take Ownership of Registry Key?

Tags: registry, inno-setup

Does anyone here know how to use Inno Setup to take ownership of registry keys such as the Security Center registry key on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

In Inno setup Help file see **[Registry] section**

You will Found **Permissions  parameter**  this will help you to take ownership of registry keys.

But keep in mind

1.current user must be able to change the permissions on the registry key

2.This parameter should only be used on registry keys private to your application. Never change the ACLs on a top-level key like HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE, otherwise you can open up security holes on your users' systems.

Check the [Inno-setup [Registry] Section Here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection)